# Unable to import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApplication in Play Frame work application

Tags: java, firebase, playframework, sbt

I am trying to add Firebase in my play framework project. I followed the following link 
https://medium.com/@RICEaaron/scala-firebase-da433df93bd2#.m1fwlvc8l

I am done with following steps

1. created project in firebase developer console
2. generated private server key and downloaded the json file
3. Added firebase server sdk dependency in `build.sbt`

This is my build.sbt code:

```
name := """NeutrinoRPM"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaCore,
  "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "3.0-M3",
  "org.julienrf" %% "play-jsmessages" % "1.6.2",
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.4.Final",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.9",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.0",  
  "com.nimbusds" % "nimbus-jose-jwt" % "3.8.2",
  "com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.3.12",
  "org.webjars" % "swagger-ui" % "2.1.8-M1",
  "com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.21.0",
  "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-analytics" % "v3-rev127-1.21.0",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.6.2",
  "com.google.http-client" % "google-http-client-gson" % "1.21.0",
  "org.apache.pdfbox" % "pdfbox" % "2.0.1",
  "com.google.firebase" % "firebase-server-sdk" % "3.0.1"
)
```

Now I am trying to initialize the Firebase server SDK with this code snippet:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();
```

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

But when i try to import

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseApplication
com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
com.google.firebase.database
```

I get this error: `The import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApplication can not be resolved`

I spent too many hours on google to search the solution to my problem but ended up with no help. Please help me.

Comment: (not related to your problem) PDFBox is at 2.0.4 now.

Answer (score 2):

Your dependency on the Firebase server SDK is old:

```
"com.google.firebase" % "firebase-server-sdk" % "3.0.1"
```

For new Firebase projects created through firebase.google.com, you should be using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) when running in the JVM.  The maven dependency is `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.1.0`.

There is no FirebaseApplication in that SDK - perhaps you are instead looking for [FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I needed to run a command activator eclipse and restart eclipse to make import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp work. Thanks for telling me about the latest version of firebase sdk.